# How to connect content to different pages in Xcode 4.5. iOS 6

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode4.5

Its my first time using a multiview app, and im trying to make the information from view one stay copied over to page 2. There are 3 numbers that i need to copy from page one over to page 2, say X, Y, and Z. How would i go about doing this? Would i localize the three variables?

Answer (score 1):

you use UINavigationController for goes one page to another page u download  sample code this link:

http://mobile.tutsplus.com/tutorials/iphone/navigation-controllers-and-view-controller-hierarchies/